# Class Not found in AppKernel.php

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, namespaces

I'm trying to deploy my Symfony2 project. When I run the command

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'Acme\MainBundle\AcmeMainBundle' not found in /var/www/html/app/AppKernal.php on line 24
```

This is the in AppKernal.php

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        ...
        new Acme\MainBundle\AcmeMainBundle(),
    );
    ...
}
```

It seems like there's a problem with the namespace?

Comment: is the classes auto loaded or manually loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure. What do you mean / how do I figure out?

Answer (score 13):

If you are getting a bundle not found error in Symfony, in composer.json, modify the `psr-4` section under `autoload` section like this.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
},
```

By doing so, you don't have to explicitly add the new bundle namespaces when you create a new bundle.

Comment: Lifesaver ! I just spent hours to find this. I think I got this `AppBundle\\...` default configuration from `composer require symfony/symfony`

Answer (score 7):

If this happened in Symfony 3 (I haven't tested this in symfony 2),

1. Make sure your bundle is registered in AppKernal.php as:

   ```
   public function registerBundles()
   {
       $bundles = array(
           ...
           new YourBundle\YourBundle(),
       );
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Check if you've updated composer.json

   ```
   "autoload": {
       "psr-4": {
           "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
           "YourBundle\\": "src/YourBundle"
       },
       "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
   },
   ```
3. Run `composer update` from your console

Answer (score 5):

Got the same problem. 
I've just deleted my vendor folder

```
rm -rf vendor
```

and relaunch a composer update.. then everything was fine

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem after adding a bundle with the code generator with Symfony 3.2. I had to add this new bundle in the autoload section of composer.json after the AppBundle :

```
(...)
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "CoreBundle\\": "src/CoreBundle"
    },
(...)
```

Comment: and run from console "composer dump-autoload"

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i needed to add this to the autoloader. Thanks @DevZer0's comment.

`$loader->add('Acme',   __DIR__ . '/../src');`

Comment: Where did you have to add this?  In `app/autoload.php`?

Comment: Sorry it's been a while. I don't remember. That seems correct.

Comment: This is not the solution, this is just an workaround/patch (although it might work).

Comment: These files are auto-generated by Composer. You will loose manual changes on the next composer install, require, update or dumpautoload run.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem?

sudo rm -rf vendor/

```
composer install
```

or

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the whole folder wasn't very convincing for me, so I tried doing just the following and it worked:

```
$ composer update
```

Then I checked it with:

```
$ php bin/console assets:install web --symlink
$ php bin/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experience all the above errors before, but I found a similar issue when running `php app/console doctrine:migrations:status`.

The issue was that I had not imported a constant which was being used as part of an annotation. For example:

```
/**
 * Either "OUTBOUND" (we send out) or "INBOUND" (we receive).
 *
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Direction", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
 *
 * @Assert\Choice(
 *     choices = {BatchDirections::OUTBOUND,BatchDirections::INBOUND},
 *     message = "Choose a valid direction."
 * )
 */
private $Direction = BatchDirections::INBOUND;
```

I hadn't imported the BatchDirections file.

Resolving the import with `use Nora\BatchBundle\Constants\BatchDirections;` fixed the issue.